# Make condition in Apache Avro Schema

Tags: schema, data-modeling, avro

I am new to apche avro, I understand many apache avro techniques, But now I want to  add conditions in Apache avro schema. Is it possible?
Like using IF Else in apache avro.

Comment: i do not think it is possible, can you provide a specific use case?

Comment: Yes, I get a response from server like status code 200, and I want that avro has some value that will replace 200, in simple word If I get status code 200 I want OK replace 200